# RegEx: Allow value only once

Tags: java, regex

I have a string of numbers and each number can appear either zero or one time in the string. Can I validate this via RegEx? I could do something like check the character array for duplicates, but would prefer to stick to my normal validation routine.

The following should return "Match"

```
String thisItemText = "12679";
if(!thisItemText.matches("[1245679]*")) {
    System.out.println("No Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

The following should return "No Match" (note the double "2")

```
String thisItemText = "122679";
if(!thisItemText.matches("[1245679]*")) {
    System.out.println("No Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

Comment: Because regular expressions are grammatical rules for regular languages (see Sipser's book, if you need to) and what you are looking for is not one. You have to write a custom parser for this.

Comment: You can do it using regular expressions - with a *capture group* `()` and a *back-reference* to the (first) capture group `\1`. See MRAB's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex `(\d).*\1` will match if there's a repeated digit.

Comment: @leonbloy: It'll attempt to match a digit, any number of characters, and then the same digit. They don't have to be consecutive.

Comment: +1 and `(\d)[\d]*\1` if he don't want to allow non digit characters in the middle of it

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern:

```
"(?<=([0-9]))(?:(?!\\1).)*\\1(?!\\1)"
```

will match a string that has any repeating digits. So if it does not match then it does not have any repeating digits.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex you need:

```
(?:([1245679])(?!\\1))+
```

The following returns "Match"

```
String thisItemText = "12679";
if(!thisItemText.matches("(?:([1245679])(?!\\1))+")) {
    System.out.println("No Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

The following returns "No Match"

```
String thisItemText = "122679";
if(!thisItemText.matches("(?:([1245679])(?!\\1))+")) {
    System.out.println("No Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("Match");
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There is solution without regexp, assume char set is ASCII

```
public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str)
{
    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (char_set[val]) return false;
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use `(1245679)*` as the regex if you are looking for *exactly* that sequence of numbers, if not, what you are looking for cannot be accomplished using regular expressions, and you have to use a custom parser.